# Displaying data on a Form in C# from a Biometric Device

Tags: c#

Through my C# Code i can successfully connect to a Biometric device, Ping it etc. I have added a user record(Employee Number, Card Number) in the device from device menu(the device is from ZKteco Company). The user access is based only on Card(fingerprint is not required). Now i want to display this record using C# on a Form(let us say in a TextBox). Can anybody please guide me how to do it?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Best Regards 
MS

Comment: Does this help? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started . Where have You problems?

Comment: doesn't the device have documentation about its interface / API?